# PHP PDO Looping through SQL results shows only the last one

Tags: php, mysql, json, pdo

Dears,

I am trying to fetch all SQL results into an assoc array and then to json but i don't know why i am only getting the last sql row.

```
<?php
require_once "Xsecure/access.php";

        $Arry = array(); 
        $json = array();

        $access = new DatabaseAccess();
        $sql = $access->Connect();
        $stmt = $sql->prepare("select mid from players");
        $stmt->execute();
        $rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();  

        $Arry = $result;


    while ($result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
        $Arry = $result;
    }
        // for array data access
        foreach($Arry as $row){
          $json["mid"] = $row["mid"];
        };

        // 3. Disconnect db connection
        $sql = $access->Disconnect();

        // 4. Return json output
        echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

?>
```

The result output is :

```
{
"mid": "10"
}
```

It should mid from 1 to 10 not only the last row. How can i achieve that? what am i missing?

Note: Later on, i want to add extra keys value pairs to the array that are not derived from mySql database so i have to use assoc array.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: `fetchAll()` provides the full result set in an array already, why aren't you just using that?

Comment: Don't loop, just do `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` or loop a `fetch()`.

Comment: Later on, i want to add extra keys value pairs to the array that are not derived from mySql database.

Comment: You're making this way more complicated than you need to, you are using PDO; all you need to do is `$stmt = $sql->prepare("select mid from players");` then `$stmt->execute();` then `echo json_encode($stmt->fetchAll(), JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I know this method but i need to add extra key value pairs to Json that are not derived from mySql. That is why i am making it more complicated hehe.

Comment: @Aboodnet Still more complicated then it needs to be even given what you just said, `$stmt->fetchAll()` returns an array, just loop through that with a foreach loop. Right now you are generating an array, looping through that to create an array, then looping through that to create another array. EDIT: Yeah, like that answer says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
...
$stmt->execute();
$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
$Arry = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($Arry as $row){
   $json[]["mid"] = $row["mid"];
};
...
```

or even just

```
...
$stmt->execute();
$rowCount = $stmt->rowCount();
$json = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
...
```

Comment: Op said "_i need to add extra key value pairs to Json that are not derived from mySql_", so adding a reference to the foreach loop would probably be pretty beneficial

Comment: so far looking at the code fragment provided OP - there is just mess of nothing.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you, I'm talking about a comment though

Comment: I modified my code accordingly but i am still getting the last row only :(

Comment: You are getting it where? Do you have any proof that there are more than 1 records returned by that query? I've edited my answer, check small but important update `$json[]["mid"] = $row["mid"];` or use last solution provided `$json = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: @Alex, yes when i just use  "echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);" without while or foreach loops, i get all the results

Comment: @Alex, i am so sorry i didn't put [] right after $json. Now it works fine and shows all the records from 1 till 10 :D